# how to deal with 503 response code java.net

Tags: java, networking

Would the following be an appropriate way of dealing with a 503 response code in java networking? What does this code- specifically the calls to disconnect and null do?

```
URL url = new URL(some url);
HttpURLConnection h =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
int x = h.getResponseCode();
while(x==503)
{
    h.disconnect();
    h = null;
    h =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    x = h.getResponseCode();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disconnect() closes the underlying TCP socket.

Setting the local variable to null immediately before reassigning it accomplishes nothing whatsoever.

There should be a sleep in that loop, with an interval that increases on every failure, and a limited number of retries.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want it to do is an appropriate way. To make something failsafe, it would be better to repeat until success is achieved, rather than *only* handling a 503 scenario.

simplest example: loop until 200 (success) code comes back.

(better would be to abstract that out into methods and classes and use OOP and unit tests where possible.)

Comment: -1 From a general standpoint, that is a very bad idea. For instance: 3XX response-codes (redirects) are not likely to be different no matter how many requests you make. Neither are 4XX codes (bad request/unauthorized or 501 (not implemented) is equally unlikely to change (until it's been implemented). In fact, look at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html and you'll see that actually pretty few codes are of a non-permanent nature. If you want to maintain some general adherence to the HTTP protocol, you need a little more refined error handling.

Comment: I agree, I wasn't advocating that was a correct approach, just pointing out that adding 'hacks' for things like 503 isn't really looking at the 'big picture' of how the application works.